# Explain why I have to return super(customlist, self).pop(x) instead of calling directly

Tags: python, methods, return, super

Why do I have to return this super pop list method call instead of calling it directly. I have a custom list class (CustomAppendList), which has a customized .append() which worked like this > `super(CustomAppendList, self).append(item)`

```
def pop(self, item):
    # print('pop')
    if type(self[item]) == card.Card:
        self[item].prior_card_group_name = self.card_group_name
        if self.card_group_name in player.Player.meld_group_dict:
            self[item].prior_meld_num = self.meld_num
    elif type(self[item]) == CustomAppendList:
        self[item][0].prior_card_group_name = self.card_group_name
        if self.card_group_name in player.Player.meld_group_dict:
            self[item][0].prior_meld_num = self.meld_num
    return super(CustomAppendList, self).pop(item)
```

I'm assuming it has to do with the fact that .pop() returns an index, while .append() doesn't, but I like to understand 'why' I am required to return the .pop() call. Wouldn't calling the .pop() directly cause the original .pop() method to be run, which returns the item passed to it from the super call?

I'm relatively new to coding, so forgive if I am not using proper terminology. Please correct me where I am wrong in any details or descriptions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `pop()` returns the item popped, not the index.  It looks like the intent of this overridden method is to do some stuff to the item that is going to be popped before actually popping it.  Calling an overridden method does *not* automagically call the parent method (maybe you don't want the overridden method to call the parent method at all because your function already accomplishes the same thing a different way), which is why `super()` exists.

Comment: The question would be more clear if you included some code to show how you think it might work (like just removing the `super()` call, or removing your function and calling the parent `pop()` directly -- I'm not actually sure which one you mean by "calling the .pop() directly" because you don't say *which* pop() or where you'd be calling it).  You could probably also answer your own question by just running that code once you wrote it.

Comment: "Wouldn't calling the .pop() directly cause the original .pop() method to be run" No; it would cause *this* `pop` method to be called, recursively. After all, `self` is *still* an instance of the derived class, so looking up `pop` on it will find the derived implementation. That's *why `super` exists*. Unless I misunderstand what you mean by " instead of calling it directly". It's only possible to debug code that you actually show to us - if you want to know why X doesn't work and you have to do Y instead, *showing X* is more important.

Comment: Did you instead mean "why do I have to write anything at all there?"? Were you expecting that, after running the derived `pop`, it would *automatically* call the base `pop` and return that result? It doesn't ever work like that, at least in Python. Not even for `__init__`. The base method only gets used if *no derived method is given at all*.

Comment: That said, whatever problem you are trying to solve by deriving from `list` *should probably not be* attempted that way.

Comment: I created a card game using pygame. I wanted to make it so that whenever the card was popped from a card group, it would assign to the card certain attributes based on that card group. My question, more specifically is: 'why does .pop() have to be returned, while .append() on the same custom list class not require use of return?' 

When using .append(), I just type 'super(CustomAppendList, self).append(item)', not 'return super(CustomAppendList, self).append(item)'. From my experience, using .pop() required me returning it, while .append() did not.